# Upgrade to Magento CE 1.9.1 is blocked by Lib_google_checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

There seems to be a circular dependency problem upgrading form CE 1.9.0.1 to CE 1.9.1.0.

When I try to upgrade Mag_Core_Modules from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1.0, it complains:

> Checking dependencies of packages
>
> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.1.0 conflicts
>   with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.0.1
>
> Checking dependencies of packages
>  Already installed:
>   community/Lib_Varien 1.9.1.0, skipping
>  Already installed:
>   community/Lib_Js_Calendar 1.51.1.1, skipping
>  Already installed:
>   community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.1.0, skipping
>  Already installed:
>   community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.5.0.0, skipping
>  Already installed:
>   community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.1.0, skipping
>  Already installed:
>   community/Lib_Magento 1.9.1.0, skipping
>  Already installed:
>   community/Lib_Credis 1.8.0.0, skipping
>  Already installed:
>   community/Lib_Pelago 1.9.1.0, skipping
>  Already installed:
>   community/Lib_ZF 1.12.7.0, skipping
>  Already installed:
>   community/Lib_Js_Prototype 1.7.0.0.5, skipping
>  Already installed:
>   community/Lib_ZF_Locale 1.12.7.0, skipping
>
> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.1.0 conflicts
>   with: community/Aramex_Shipping_Tracking_API 2.0.1
>  Package
>   community/Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.1.0 conflicts with:
>   community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.0.1
>  Package community/Lib_Mage
>   1.9.1.0 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.0.1

I'm not bothered by Aramex at this stage, but when I try to upgrade Lib_Google_Checkout 1.9.1.0, it can't because of the conflict with Mag_core

Could this mean that Aramex blocks the upgrade to Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.1.0, and the whole thing cascades from there?

Answer (score 1):

Google checkout was discontinued awhile back, I'd say you're safe with wiping it or forcing/skipping it.

> Google Checkout has been retired. You can no longer process orders. The last day to process refunds will be December 20, 2013.

- https://checkout.google.com/seller/fees.html

Also (if your core codebase is not hacked to bits) I wouldn't recommend upgrading via Magento Connect and would do it manually via shell, or simply overwriting the new codebase from a fresh install.

Comment: There are significant hacks in our code, so overwriting is not the route for me.

I've tried to remove lib_google_checkout, but it claims it is needed by Magento.

I'm making a copy of the VM to play with so I can figure out what to do and I'll report back when I have a result.

Comment: If there are hacks, then Connect will most likely overwrite them. I would do a diff to compare and re-apply (without core hacks, obviously to avoid these headaches in the future)

Comment: Thinking about this: The hacks are done correctly, ie, they are not changes to core files, but additional files in the right directories.  I guess then whether I upgrade with connect or do it from the shell, the changes will stay. I'll first try it on my test copy and see how it works.